# Inserting elements into multi-linked list in ascending order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I have constructed a multi-linked list made up of `Friend` objects. The `Friend` class has `name` and `age` field. I am trying to insert the `Friend` objects in ascending order by comparing the names, but I'm running into issues with the part of my code that handles two matching names.

I'm either getting null pointer exceptions or the printed list is out of order.

Populating the list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
    l.add("Travis", 19);
    l.add("Kyler", 14);
    l.add("Abby", 10);
    l.add("Bob", 19);
    l.add("Travis", 12);
    l.add("Zander", 99);
    l.printList();
}
```

`LinkedList` class:

```
public class LinkedList {

    Friend head;
    int listcount;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
        listcount = 0;
    }

    public void add(String name, int age){
        Friend node = new Friend(name,age);
        if(head==null){
            head = node;
            return;
        }
        if(head.name.compareTo(node.name) > 0){
            node.nextName = head;
            head = node;
            return;
        }
        Friend current = head;
        Friend previous = null;

        while(current.name.compareTo(node.name) < 0 && current.nextName != null){
            previous = current;
            current = current.nextName;
        }
        if(current.name.compareTo(node.name) == 0 && current.age < node.age){
            node.nextName = current.nextName;
            current.nextName = node;
        }
        previous.nextName = node;
        node.nextName = current;
    }
    public void printList(){
        Friend temp = head;
        while(temp!=null){
            temp.print();
            temp = temp.nextName;
        }
    }
}
```

`Friend` class:

```
public class Friend {
    String name;
    int age;
    Friend nextName;
    Friend nextAge;

    public Friend(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        nextName = null;
        nextAge = null;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(name+" "+age+". ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a first problem is that `Friend` should not have to maintain a reference to the next `Friend`. You should create a `Node` class for that and *separate responsibilities*.

Comment: I was trying to make `Friend` act as the `Node` class. What does separating the two allow me to do?

Comment: It is said to be [*code smell/antipattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) (a sign of bad code design) if one class is responsible for many things at once. You should *separate responsibilities*.

Comment: I think `Node<T>` ( here `Node<Friend>` ) is the right way to go. apart from that, I don't know how to suggest the bugfixing... it seems that you wrote a very strange linkedlist...

Comment: Why not use `TreeMap` with `Comparator` on name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your add() like this(I mean the last lines of your add() method) ;

```
    if (current.name.compareTo(node.name) == 0 && current.age < node.age) {
        node.nextName = current.nextName;
        current.nextName = node;
    } else if (current.name.compareTo(node.name) < 0 ) {
        previous.nextName = current;            
        current.nextName = node;
    } else {
        previous.nextName = node;
        node.nextName = current;
    }
```

Output

> > Abby 10. 
> >     Bob 19. 
> >     Kyler 14. 
> >     Travis 12. 
> >     Travis 19. 
> >     Zander 99.

Comment: This works with the input that I used in the question, but if you only use `name` strings that are equal to each other it throws a `null pointer exception`. Thanks for the help though!